# How do you reset a form after OK is clicked in a confirm box?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reset

I have a form with a reset button that clears the whole form, but I want a confirm dialog box to pop up and confirm the user wants to reset.

I have the confirm box working, but how do I make it reset the form when the *OK* button is pressed?

Below is the code I have so far:

```js
function reset() {
  var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to reset all text?");
  if (r == true) {
    form.reset();
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Full Name</p><br><input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
  <p>Address</p><input name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address"><br>
  <p>Email</p><br><input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
  <input type="submit"> <button onclick="reset()" type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="reset" onclick="return confirm_reset();">
```

JS:

```
function confirm_reset() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to reset all text?");
}
```

When the `onclick` function returns `false`, it prevents the default action of the reset button.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4L2d6/)

Comment: Might as well put in the confirm() inside the onclick itself instead of making a new function... Just use single quotes for the text.

Comment: That's a matter of style. I prefer to keep my `onclick` attributes small.

Answer (score 1):

add an id to your form then just...

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

[met form reset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried getElementById but instead of just ".reset()" i had put "form.reset()".

Comment: Might as well take advantage of features HTML provides you... Give the `<form>` a `name="myForm"` attribute, and then you can access it with `document.forms.myForm.reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<button>` element of type `reset` and the standard method [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> The `Event` interface's `preventDefault()` method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be....Calling `preventDefault()` during any stage of event flow cancels the event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not occur.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}

[type="reset"] {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Full Name</legend>
    <input name="name">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Address</legend>
    <input name="address">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Email</legend>
    <input name="email" type="email">
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JQuery** for this !

**HTML:**

```
<input type="reset">
```

**JS - JQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="reset"]', function(e){
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to reset form data?")){}
  else{
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location="#";
  }
});
```